# How to boot from USB iso on Ubuntu using VMWare?

Tags: boot, grub2, vmware

I am installing Elastix as an iso file from a USB drive to an Ubuntu in VMWare. Everything I found online is about booting Linux on a USB.

I tried reconfiguring the grub2 to load the Elastix.iso file to no avail.

I thought of installing elastix directly to Ubuntu with apt-get install, but it's not the same package as the one I'm downloading.

Finally, I tried the start up disk creator, but it just doesn't load the iso file if I copied it into Documents.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In VMware once Ubuntu is up and running.
Load `Elastix.iso` file into the "virtual cd drive" of Ubuntu.
Then inside Ubuntu run the .iso as normal.
If it doesn't autorun try:
`cd /media/cdrom0`

Look for a `.sh` or a executable file
Run `ls -l` to see what's executable

Finally, `./nameOfFile.sh`
`.iso` is just an image file of a CD or DVD and can be treated as such